# INSERT INTO truncates concatenated table values to 255 characters in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've got the following problem with MS Access:

I have many tables, all of them with only 2 columns (one of the columns works as a PK to identify the rows - In the first 3 examples, it will be the column "Name") and i need to concatenate every value from every column into one field in another table, something like:

TABLE 1:

```
    Name      |    Number
--------------------------
    Charlie   |      1
    Charlie   |      2
    James     |      3
    James     |      4
    Michelle  |      5
    Michelle  |      6
```

TABLE 2:

```
    Name      |      Country
------------------------------
    Charlie   |      Brazil
    Charlie   |      France
    James     |      Japan
    Michelle  |       USA
```

TABLE 3 - TABLES that totalizes the concatenation:

```
    Name      |    Number   |     Country
----------------------------------------------
    Charlie   |     1,2     |  Brazil,France
    James     |     3,4     |      Japan
    Michelle  |     5,6     |       USA
```

Until now, I was able to create an append that uses a function in VBA to concatenate these values to the fields in Table 3 without problems when i've got few values in the collumns.

The function is avaiable in: http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html and follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ConcatRelated(strField As String, _
    strTable As String, _
    Optional strWhere As String, _
    Optional strOrderBy As String, _
    Optional strSeparator = ", ") As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Generate a concatenated string of related records.
    'Return:    String variant, or Null if no matches.
    'Arguments: strField = name of field to get results from and concatenate.
    '           strTable = name of a table or query.
    '           strWhere = WHERE clause to choose the right values.
    '           strOrderBy = ORDER BY clause, for sorting the values.
    '           strSeparator = characters to use between the concatenated values.
    'Notes:     1. Use square brackets around field/table names with spaces or odd characters.
    '           2. strField can be a Multi-valued field (A2007 and later), but strOrderBy cannot.
    '           3. Nulls are omitted, zero-length strings (ZLSs) are returned as ZLSs.
    '           4. Returning more than 255 characters to a recordset triggers this Access bug:
    '               http://allenbrowne.com/bug-16.html
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         'Related records
    Dim rsMV As DAO.Recordset       'Multi-valued field recordset
    Dim strSql As String            'SQL statement
    Dim strOut As String            'Output string to concatenate to.
    Dim lngLen As Long              'Length of string.
    Dim bIsMultiValue As Boolean    'Flag if strField is a multi-valued field.

    'Initialize to Null
    ConcatRelated = Null

    'Build SQL string, and get the records.
    strSql = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strTable
    If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    If strOrderBy <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy
    End If
    Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
    'Determine if the requested field is multi-valued (Type is above 100.)
    bIsMultiValue = (rs(0).Type > 100)

    'Loop through the matching records
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If bIsMultiValue Then
            'For multi-valued field, loop through the values
            Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
            Do While Not rsMV.EOF
                If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
                    strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
                End If
                rsMV.MoveNext
            Loop
            Set rsMV = Nothing
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
            strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    'Return the string without the trailing separator.
    lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    'Clean up
    Set rsMV = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

The problem is: Even using Memo fields in Table 3 (Tables 1 & 2 use Text now, but i tested with memo and they didn't work either), my concatenation doesn't let me concatenate too many values, and I dont get every value needed into table 3 when my origin collumn is too big.

My Query:

```
INSERT INTO 
    [0A - Totalizador] ( Operadora, NDC_MSISDN )
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [1A - Paises].Operadora, 
    ConcatRelated("[NDC]","[1A - NDC_MSISDN]","[Operadora] =""" & [Operadora] & """","[NDC]",", ") AS Expr1, 
FROM 
    [1A - Paises];
```

Exemple of wrong output:

ORIGIN TABLE:

```
Operadora   |     NDC
--------------------------
   NAME          70100 
   NAME          70101 
   NAME          70102 
   NAME          70103 
   NAME          801 
   NAME          802 
   NAME          80769 
   NAME          8077
   NAME          8078
   NAME          80790 
   NAME          80791 
   NAME          80792 
   NAME          808 
   NAME          8092
   NAME          8095
   NAME          8099
   NAME          9010
   NAME          90111 
   NAME          90112 
   NAME          9014
   NAME          9015
   NAME          9016
   NAME          90187 
   NAME          90188 
   NAME          90189 
   NAME          90198 
   NAME          90199 
   NAME          9021
   NAME          9022
   NAME          9023
   NAME          9024
   NAME          9025
   NAME          9026
   NAME          9027
   NAME          9030
   NAME          9031
   NAME          9032
   NAME          9033
   NAME          90340 
   NAME          90346 
   NAME          90888
   NAME          1000
   NAME          2000
   NAME          3000
   NAME          4000
```

OUTPUT TABLE: (THAT IS WRONGLY BEING RETURNED)

```
 Operadora  |                 NDC
------------------------------------------------------
            | 70100, 70101, 70102, 70103, 801, 802, 
            | 80769, 8077, 8078, 80790, 80791, 80792, 
            | 808, 8092, 8095, 8099, 9010, 90111, 90112, 
    NAME    | 9014, 9015, 9016, 90187, 90188, 90189, 
            | 90198, 90199, 9021, 9022, 9023, 9024, 9025, 
            | 9026, 9027, 9030, 9031, 9032, 9033, 90340, 
            | 90346, 9
```

OUTPUT TABLE (THAT SHOULD BE BEING RETURNED):

```
 Operadora  |                 NDC
------------------------------------------------------
            | 70100, 70101, 70102, 70103, 801, 802, 
            | 80769, 8077, 8078, 80790, 80791, 80792, 
            | 808, 8092, 8095, 8099, 9010, 90111, 90112, 
    NAME    | 9014, 9015, 9016, 90187, 90188, 90189, 
            | 90198, 90199, 9021, 9022, 9023, 9024, 9025, 
            | 9026, 9027, 9030, 9031, 9032, 9033, 90340, 
            | 90346, 90888, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000
```

I can't figure out a way to solve this... 
Can someone please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating many values to a field in ACCESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786272/concatenating-many-values-to-a-field-in-access)

Comment: That pesky ole' 255 character limit strikes again...

Comment: @Blackhawk - Not a dupe.  A new wrinkle in the solution that was provided in that question.

Comment: This might take a while and be a pain the the keyster, but put a breakpoint on the rs.MoveNext line and check the value of strOut on each iteration.  If the last iteration shows you the full expected string, then it's a problem in the table.  If the last iteration doesn't show you the full expected string, then there's a problem with the variable.

Comment: I'm used to breakpoint in Netbeans and Visual Studio, but not on VBA... I'll take a look and post as soon as possibru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I could work around the issue by moving the DISTINCT keyword into a subquery in the FROM clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    [0A - Totalizador] ( Operadora, NDC_MSISDN )
SELECT 
    Operadora, 
    ConcatRelated("[NDC]","[1A - NDC_MSISDN]","[Operadora] =""" & [Operadora] & """","[NDC]",", ") AS Expr1
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT Operadora 
        FROM [1A - Paises]
    );
```

Comment: Any ideas as to why that would make a difference, just for S & G's?  There are no repeated values in his list, so theorhetically the DISTINCT operator is moot.

Comment: @JohnnyBones SELECT DISTINCT is known to truncate string values to 255 characters. There are other causes, too; look [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html) for details.

Comment: Crazy.  Good stuff, though!  +1 for the info.

Comment: I will take a look at this and will reply when possible. Thanks for the help, mate! Asap I'll reply

Comment: @GordThompson, OH MY GOD, I THINK IT WORKS!